# How to Mock IMongoDatabase

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, moq

I'm using Moq for mocking my objects in an ASP.NET Core project.

I want to mock the following IsConnection() method:

```
public Client(IMongoClient client)
{
    _client = client;
}

public async Task<bool> IsConectionOk()
{            
    var pingCommand = new BsonDocument("ping", 1);
    var mongoDb = _client.GetDatabase("Name");
    var commandResult = await mongoDb.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(pingCommand);
    return commandResult != null;        
}
```

As you see, there's only one injection, `IMongoClient`, so I need to mock this one. Now, I need to mock `IMongoDatabase` as well since the `_client.GetDatabase` returns me an `IMongoDatabase` which runs `RunCommandAsync`

this is my unit test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task IsConnectionOk_xxx_RunPing1Command()
{
    var dbMock = new Mock<IMongoDatabase>();
    var resultCommand = new BsonDocument("ok", 1);
    dbMock.Setup(stub => stub.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(It.IsAny<BsonDocument>(), It.IsAny<ReadPreference>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(resultCommand);

    var mongoClientMock = new Mock<IMongoClient>();
    mongoClientMock.Setup(stub => stub.GetDatabase(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<MongoDatabaseSettings>())).Returns(dbMock.Object);

    var client = new Client(mongoClientMock.Object);
    var pingCommand = new BsonDocument("ping", 1);

    //act
    await client.IsConectionOk();

    //assert
    dbMock.Verify(mock => mock.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>( It.Is<BsonDocument>(x => x.Equals(pingCommand)) , It.IsAny<ReadPreference>() ,It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
}
```

You can see that I mocked a `IMongoDatabase` so my `mongoClientMock` can return it when the code is executing. When code is running, I have checked that `mongoClientMock.GetDatabase()` is returning a `MongoDatabase` (good until there), the **problem** is that when `MongoDatabaseMock` calls **RunCommandAsync** is not returning what I set up, it just returns **null**. I don't know what I could be missing here, any thoughts?

Comment: Verify also wont work as they have differing instances.

Comment: @Nkosi also, what did you mean with 'Verify won't work' ? My mongoClientMock.GetDatabase() should return dbMock that is setup at the start of the test so it's the same instance, am I missing something?

Comment: You initialize a command outside of the method under test and try to verify that it (the instance) was used in the mock. that verify will fail.

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to test and verify in the method under test?

Comment: @Nkosi I just edited again, the IsConnection() method checks that the resultCommand is not null, so first, I need to mock MongoDatabase and setup the RunCommandAsync method so my test passes. And my full goal is to check that RunCommandAsync was called with pingCommand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things are a little tricky here.

Some background first.

According to documentation, `IMongoDatabase.RunCommandAsync<TResult>` is defined as

```
Task<TResult> RunCommandAsync<TResult>(
    Command<TResult> command,
    ReadPreference readPreference = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = null
)
```

Note the `Command<TResult>`, while in your code you pass a `BsonDocument`.

Luckily `BsonDocument` has an implicit conversion operator from `BsonDocument` to `Command<TResult>`

When a setup does not get what was configured it tends to return null. So you need to make sure that it is setup properly so that it performs the expected behavior.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task _IsConnectionOk_xxx_RunPing1Command() {
        var dbMock = new Mock<IMongoDatabase>();
        var resultCommand = new BsonDocument("ok", 1);
        dbMock
            .Setup(stub => stub.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(It.IsAny<Command<BsonDocument>>(), It.IsAny<ReadPreference>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(resultCommand)
            .Verifiable();

        var mongoClientMock = new Mock<IMongoClient>();
        mongoClientMock
            .Setup(stub => stub.GetDatabase(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<MongoDatabaseSettings>()))
            .Returns(dbMock.Object);

        var client = new Client(mongoClientMock.Object);
        var pingCommand = new BsonDocument("ping", 1);

        //act
        var actual = await client.IsConectionOk();

        //assert
        Assert.IsTrue(actual);
        dbMock.Verify();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found my problem, take a look at the next line:

```
dbMock.Setup(stub => stub.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(It.IsAny<BsonDocument>(), It.IsAny<ReadPreference>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(resultCommand);
```

turns out that `RunCommandAsync` first parameter is a `Command<TResult>` so the fix I needed was:

```
dbMock.Setup(stub => stub.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(It.IsAny<Command<BsonDocument>>(), It.IsAny<ReadPreference>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(anyResultCommand);
```

And problem solved!